# Kubernetes Hostpath External Provisioner fails to instantiate in a POD: Failed to create config

Tags: kubernetes, external, provisioning

I am trying to deploy [hostpath external provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/docs/demo/hostpath-provisioner) POD on a single-node Kubernetes cluster v1.5.1. I built the provisioner image in my workstation, saved the docker image to a tar file and loaded it on my single-node K8S cluster and the image loaded successfully. However when I try to create a POD using it, POD goes into CrashLoopBackOff, and when I check the POD logs, I see the following error:

```
Failed to create config: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

I guess this error is thrown from the following line in hostpath-provisioner.go's main() function:

```
config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
```

My pod definition is here:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hostpath-provisioner
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hostpath-provisioner
      image: hostpath-provisioner:latest
      imagePullPolicy: "Never"
      env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
      volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-volume
          mountPath: /tmp/hostpath-provisioning
  volumes:
    - name: pv-volume
      hostPath:
        path: /tmp/hostpath-provisioning
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: How did you build your cluster? You seem to have missed a step.

Comment: The usual way, on a debian variant. I can create PODs, Services, etc as usual and everything seems working perfectly including exposing the services via NodePort.  Docs say the file /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token is automatically created  by K8S in the container, but I don't see it in a regular nginx container too. kube-controller is started with root- ca file:

Comment: `/hyperkube controller-manager --address=127.0.0.1 --master=https://172.17.24.94:6443 --kubeconfig=/var/opt/hcoe/kubernetes/conf/ssl/kubeconfig.yaml --root-ca-file=/var/auth/cacert.pem --pod-eviction-timeout=1m0s --v=4 --log-dir=/var/log/k8s-controller --logtostderr=false`